# Visual Studio 2019 error CTC1001: Volume sharing is not enabled

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to build a docker image for my NETCORE application, but when I run "Build Docker image" menu from Visual Studio, it throw an error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read
> dockerfile: open
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount861662899/dockerfile: no such file
> or directory
> 5>C:\Users\xxxx.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.9.10\build\Container.targets(198,5):
> error CTC1001: Volume sharing is not enabled. On the Settings screen
> in Docker Desktop, click Shared Drives, and select the drive(s)
> containing your project files.

When I try to enable volume sharing, I'm unable to find that option on my Docker settings. All docs says it should be under "Resources" option.

[image: Docker settings]

I'm using WSL2 integration, but don't know if it have something to do with the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I faced same issues with WSL 2 and then I just look into Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets package version used in. It was outdated and then I just install compatible version to my project using package manager, in my case it is 1.10.8 and then It this works for me.

Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets -Version 1.10.8

Answer (score 0):

It might be cause of you set Docker OS Type to linux, but Docker works as Windows container. Try to "Switch to Linux containers" in context menu of Docker tray icon or change settings of  in your .csproj file:

```
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it's not the case, my docker instance is running Linux containers.

Comment: I had the same problem on my, but my problem was in existing two different versions of Docker - Docker Toolbox and Docker Desktop and it conflicted, so there was no volumes option in settings. I removed Docker Toolbox and Docker Desktop, then install only Desktop and everything is fine now

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, just go to settings > resources > wsl integration and mark the integration as enabled:[image]